# Silverlight or ClientBin problem?

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis-7, clientbin

I have a ridiculous problem here. I got IIS 7.0, with a silverlight files in clientBin.

If I put my `.xap` up to date, my silverlight file are not update. Maybe a cache somewhere, so I deleted asp net temporary, I delete my browser cache, I also delete the .xap file in the IIS folder, and when I try to download the `.xap` again the browser gives me the silverlight file also even if it is deleted.

From where this file coming from? I try the same thing with a image in the client bin folder and I get the same bizarre problem.

What do I need to clear to refresh the `ClientBin` folder.?

I also try to reboot IIS, `iisreset`, stop the application and web site, try to force IIS to expired cache immediately, no luck with any of this.

Could somebody help me ?

Comment: hmm. How do you know which file is loading up? For me I had an SL app that displays the assembly version somewhere, when I had the same problem, so I was sure the wrong SL app was loading. It was only browser cache for me, I cleared it all and it worked. (you might need to clear all of it)

Comment: I already clear it, i also try with other navigator, ie, firefox, chrome ... and always get the "inexistant file" from the server

Comment: sure you're connected to the right server, maybe you can try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to check if a request/response is really happening.

Comment: I do it with fiddler, i try it directly on the server and i be able to download the "innexistant file". I also add a .bmp file into the ClientBin folder, try to download it with success. I delete the file, clear the cache and i receive also the .bmp file also if he deleted

Comment: that is definitely bizarre!! You sure your website on IIS is point to the right folder and not a copy of the folder (I had this once too!!).

Comment: Maybe there is some caching behavior in IIS? Can you inspect the server logs?

Comment: Assuming all the details you provide are correct then the only other place where such content might be cached on intermediatory cache server. I've seen this at times where a VPN is up on an ISA box, the ISA also ends up proxying web requests unexpectedly.

Comment: I think your right AnthonyWJones, I ask the question to our IT departement and they recently install a ForeFront server... maybe the probleme came from this device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to load your xap file with a querystring.  This will force the browser to get the latest version

```
<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/MySilverlightApp.xap?v=12345" />
```

Comment: I really dont know why and from where the file was download. Where is suppose to be cached ?

Comment: do I'm assuming @alisons solution fixed the problem?

Comment: This answer fix the probleme, but i always dont know where was make the cache of my silverligth file. Another collegue get the same probleme but is really strange